# Highcharts Dates Wrong

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, unix-timestamp, highcharts

I have the following JSON:

```
[
[1230768000,2],
[1233446400,3],
[1235865600,2],
[1238544000,6],
[1241136000,1],
[1243814400,2],
[1246406400,7],
[1249084800,3],
[1251763200,5],
[1254355200,2],
[1257033600,5],
[1259625600,4]
]
```

Should be Jan - Dec in 2009. When I view the chart, it says the first point is Thursday, Jan 15th at 05:52 and the other values are on the same day ay different time intervals.

When I run the dates through http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm they seem fine. I'm running this on IIS and using classic ASP.

Comment: how do you convert it from epoch to Date? Should work with dateAdd("s", your_epoch_value, "01/01/1970 00:00:00")

Answer (score 4):

highcharts dates need to be in milliseconds. Try multiplying them by 1000.